# What is the range of this particular function?

Tags: functions

I have $f(x)=[\cos\pi x]$, $x ∈ [-1,1]$
What is the range of this function?

My answer was that the function takes the following values for appropriate $x$. 
$-1, x ∈ [-1,\frac{1}{2}) ; $
$0, x= [-\frac{1}{2},0)$
$1, x=0 ; $
$0, x ∈ (0,\frac{1}{2}]; $
$-1,x ∈ (\frac{1}{2},1] ; $

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct:

$f(x)=-1$, for $x\in [-1,-\frac{1}{2})\cup(\frac{1}{2},1]$;

$f(x)=0$, for $x\in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]-\lbrace0\rbrace$;

$f(x)=1$, for $x=0$.

Then, $Ran(f)=\lbrace-1,0,1\rbrace$

Comment: Thank you for verifying

Answer (score 0):

Thr Range of $f(x)= [\cos \pi x]$, if [.] is GIF  is $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The range is $\{-1,0,1\}$. [ $\cos 0=1, \cos \pi =-1$ and $\cos (\frac {\pi} 2)=0$].